# Did Luke teach the traditional lightsaber forms or the "Strong" etc. styles

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, luke-skywalker

Was reading an article a couple of months ago that stated that because all material of the old republic had been destroyed Luke had no knowledge of the 7 forms of lightsaber combat other than form IV and basics of Shi-Cho

And because of this he developed 3 new styles; the ones depicted in the Jedi Outcast games; they are Light, Medium and Strong (Wish they had named them better sounds like someone who had no knowledge on Star Wars named em, anyway)

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Well, Luke had essentially no knowledge of actual Jedi History. I'm doubtful Yoda had the luxury of spending much time on history lessons and esoterica. So picking simple names from his own language makes a lot more sense than picking some poetic descriptors from another culture and language; better than the horribly mechanical "Form N", too.

Answer (score 7):

This is all Legends (the games in and the books they are loosely based on).

### Yes. He taught the traditional Form IV.

Because Luke was trained in Form IV (also know as Ataru) by Yoda, he did instruct the new generation of students in this form. However, this form didn't work for all scenarios, so with the assistance of others, they developed the Strong, Fast, and Medium forms.

> While Luke had been provided with formal training in Ataru by Master Yoda, passing this on to his own students,[41] the loss of so much knowledge from the old Jedi Order, including many lightsaber combat techniques, forced Luke's new order to essentially start from scratch. Kam Solusar trained the students in the three rings of defense, while Corran Horn trained them in many of CorSec's combat techniques.[40] The three forms of the Jedi Order were eventually created, each specializing in a different aspect of combat. The Strong style focused on brute strength and offense, often at the expense of defense. The Fast style focused on speed and precision, and was especially good for blast-deflection. The Medium style balanced out between the previous two, and oftentimes acted as a tutorial form, much like Shii-Cho for the old Jedi Order. - [Wookieepedia- Lightsaber Combat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_combat/Legends#Redevelopment)

He received only the simplist instruction in Form I (Shii-Cho) from Obi-Wan Kenobi [citation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_I/Legends#Notable_practitioners).

Eventually (after the events of the game) all forms were apparently rediscovered (according to the previous citation).

> Shii-Cho, like the other six forms, would eventually be rediscovered by the New Jedi Order

Comment: Did teaching of the Strong, Fast, and Medium forms continue after the originals were found?

Answer (score -3):

Hey yes he did in fact learned a few more. He learned form 3 soresu from obi wans journals, form 5 Djem so from watching Vader, Seven Juyo from Mace windus journals, ataru from Yoda, form 1 from a brief lesson with obi wan and Niman

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Two things: the question was what forms Luke *taught*, not what he learned.  Secondarily, if you assert a fact, you should provide a quote or a source for it.